# Hibernate: Multiple native queries grouped together

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I run the following code successfully using hibernate and postgresql 9.1

```
session.createSQLQuery("delete from table_1; delete from table_2").executeUpdate();
```

My question is: **Does hibernate officially support grouping native queries and running them together in one go?** I was not able to find such information in manual. **Are there any disadvantages or potential risks in using this solution?**

Comment: You're relying on a PostgreSQL extension, so no. Don't expect it to work with other DBs, and it could stop working at any time if Hibernate decided to try to parse native SQL for any reason (unlikely). What actual problem are you attempting to solve by doing this, anyway? What's the "why", the reason you care?

Comment: I have multiple named queries (create table, insert, analyze table, etc.) run always together and I wondered if I could grouped them into one. I checked and it worked but I was not able to find any information about this in hibernate's manual. I agree correct operation may depend on the target database. Currently hibernate does not interfere in such queries, just send them to db,

Comment: Unless you have a good reason (more than "it's convenient"), don't do this. Just send each query individually.

Comment: In case you want to apply parameters  for your queries using setParameter(), it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute multiple queries like this, however if you need to execute them like this for any reason you can put these calls in a stored procedure and call that stored procedure. However I won't recommend to use a Stored Procedure.

Comment: He can execute the queries like this. And they do work. The question - is this method officially supported by hibernate.